# Getting a mySQL error in php generated query

Tags: php, mysql

Let me try this again, because I'm not sure people got that I was running this query with php.  The query that the php function outputs runs fine in a regular mySQL program like Navicat but it throws this error, in my browser when it ran from the php script:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checklisttest; CREATE TABLE checklisttest ( Incident va' at line 2
```

Here is some of the query that is ran from within the php script:

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checklisttest;
CREATE TABLE checklisttest (
  Incident varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  TestID mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Element varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  Code varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  Expected varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  Actual varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  AutoVerifyResult varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  QAResult varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  Comments text,
  PRIMARY KEY (TestID)
);

INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E02_04','Type of Service Requested','30','911 Response (Scene)','911 RESPONSE (SCENE)','100','Pass',NULL);
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E02_11','EMS Unit/Vehicle  Number','Medic 81','Medic 81','Medic 81','100','Pass',NULL);
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E02_18','Patient Destination  Odometer Reading  of Responding  Vehicle','11','11','Not set!','0','Fail',NULL);
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E03_01','Complaint Reported  by Dispatch','410','Animal Bite','ANIMAL BITE','100','Pass',NULL);
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E04_01','Crew Member ID','EMT302875','EMT302875','EMT302875','100','Pass',NULL);
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES ('20009',NULL,'E04_01','Crew Member ID','PMD509465','PMD509465','PMD509465','100','Pass',NULL);
```

Here is the php that generates that query:

```
        private function toDB(){
        $sql = "
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS checklisttest;
CREATE TABLE checklisttest (
  Incident varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  TestID mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Element varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  Code varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  Expected varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  Actual varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  AutoVerifyResult varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  QAResult varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  Comments text,
  PRIMARY KEY (TestID)
);
              ";

    //iterate through the records $this->records[10001]
    foreach($this->records as $inc => $record){
        //iterate through the element ids $this->records[10001][E02_04]
        foreach($this->records[$inc]["Elements"] as $elementID => $element){
            //iterate through the element ids $this->records[10001][E02_04][1]
            foreach($element as $key => $val){
                $sql .= "
INSERT INTO `checklistTest` VALUES (\"$inc\",NULL,\"$elementID\",\"$val[name]\",\"$val[code]\",\"$val[expected]\",\"$val[actual]\",\"$val[match]\",\"$val[QAResult]\",NULL);";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<textarea style='width:100%;height:400px'>$sql</textarea>";
    mysql_select_db("new",$GLOBALS['local']);
    mysql_query($sql,$GLOBALS['local']) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify length for each varchar field. Moreover you have two auto_increment fields

Comment: fixed those, but I'm still getting the error, I've revised my question.

Comment: A gui sw like Navicat can run multiple queries at once if you separate them with ;. If you want to run multiple queries within php you have to call mysql_query() function for each of them, that is mysql_query("drop table ..."); mysql_query("create table ..."); and so on.

Comment: I added the php code that generates the query, i'll try what you mentioned

Comment: yup, my problem was I wanted to run all of the statements at once, I never even tried that before.  so now i know this is not possible, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

A few errors:

- You have a type called `varchar` but this is not allowed. You must specify a length, e.g. `varchar(128)`.
- The column `Actual` shouldn't be `AUTO_INCREMENT` because it is not part of a key, and you already have an auto-increment field.
- Instead of `('20009',,'E02_04',...` you probably mean `('20009',NULL,'E02_04',...` (note the extra `NULL`).

Comment: thanks, I don't know how i missed the 2nd auto_increment, what if I don't know the length of the Code, Expected and Actual fields?

Comment: @jreed121: You don't need to know the actual length. You only need to give a length that isn't too small. Just write a number that will be big enough. And if you are not sure if the number is picked will be big enough, you can enter a bigger number until you are sure.